# how do i convert list of jsonNodes to single jsonNode

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson, jackson-modules

I am using Jackson library. I have number of java objects which are nothing but the wrapper for jsonNode. So want to convert these list of jsonNodes into single jsonNode. how can i do that. i tried this

```
   public JsonNode converter(List<? extends Base> objList){
    List<String> jsonList=new ArrayList<String>();
    try
     {
    for (Base raObject : objList) {
        ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
        String json = ow.writeValueAsString(raObject);
        jsonList.add(json);
    }
     return JsonHelper.convert(jsonList); 
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
         System.out.println("Error occured while converting objectlist to jsonNode::"+e);
         return null;
    }       
}
```

this is not working. ithere any other way?

Answer (score 2):

If each of your objects can be serialized, then you should also be able to serialize a list of them to combine them into a json list:

```
mapper.writeValueAsString(objList); // produces a JSON list: "[ obj1, obj2 ...]"
```

You can also ask Jackson to simply convert the objList to an ArrayNode instead:

```
ArrayNode arrayNode = mapper.convertValue(objList, ArrayNode.class);
```

But if you actually had a method in Base to allow conversion to a JsonNode, you could simply build ArrayNode yourself:

```
ArrayNode arrayNode = mapper.getNodeFactory().arrayNode();
for (Base obj : objList) {
    arrayNode.add(obj.toJsonNode());
}
```

This would avoid round-tripping via a JSON representation.